# Logarithmic way of filtering sparse values..?

Tags: java, logic

I have a situation where I show a matrix. The matrix contain values greater than or equal to 0. So to add convenience to the user I just added a  bar slider whose minimum value is 0 and maximum value is the maximum value from the matrix. So when the user slides on  the slider I just filter the matrix cells and show only those cells which have value greater than the slider value user has slided.

My issue is that in the matrix table the values are quite sparse like there are a lot of values in the range sometime 1-5 and then 20-25 (can be other ranges also). So when i slider the tables gets reduced a lot.

I want something now that on moving the slider only a few values gets filtered. I was thinking if there is any logarithmic way of solving this problem...or may be some other way..

Answer (score 0):

If your matrix is size `M x N` consider storing the data in an array like `data[L][2]` where `L = M x N` and `data[i][0]` is the actual value while data[i][1] is the value's position in your original `M x N` matrix.

If `data[i][0]` is sorted you can process it faster to find positions with values under a given threshold.

**Example:**

Matrix

```
1 2 3
0 7 1
5 1 9
```

Array (value, position)

```
0 1 1 1 2 3 5 7 9
4 1 6 8 2 3 7 5 9
```

Cells with values less than 3: `4 1 6 8 2`